# Do "dynamic ivars" break the "strict superset of C" paradigm for Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Thank you to [Yuji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239243/yuji) for answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076836/how-do-automatic-synthesized-ivars-affect-the-real-sizeofmyclass) I had and pointing me to [this article about dynamic ivars in Objective-C](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html).

However, as explained in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076836/how-do-automatic-synthesized-ivars-affect-the-real-sizeofmyclass) the `sizeof` operator now behaves inconsistently.  In short, `sizeof` will not take into account dynamic ivars from outside the class `.m` file but will take them into account inside the `.m` file after the `@synthesize` declarations that create the dynamic ivars.

So my question is does this break the idea that Objective-C is a strict superset of C?

Comment: Either narrow your question to something that can be exactly right or wrong, or make it a community wiki question (opinions aren't really either right or wrong, though they might be "most satisfying to you").

Comment: Ok, thanks for fixing the formatting, I narrowed the question :) I'm fairly new here so I will look into what "community wiki" means for future reference, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. All valid C code remains valid Objective-C code with the same meaning it has in C, so Objective-C is still a strict superset. Keep in mind that a superset is allowed to have features not found in a subset — that's the whole reason Objective-C can have all the additional capabilities and syntax that it does while remaining 100% C-compatible.

What this does affect is the implementation detail that Objective-C classes are essentially C struct types with a set of functions that act on them. Note that similar functionality to `objC_setAssociatedObject()` *could* be implemented for a CoreFoundation-style pure C struct without changing the C language itself at all — and it would have the similar side effect of making `sizeof()` not give a fully "accurate" idea of all the data the struct encompasses.

Answer (score 3):

No.  If you run Objective-C code through a C compiler it never would have compiled anyway.  If you run C code through an Objective-C compiler it will behave exactly as if you had run it through a C compiler (barring compiler bugs).

If you ever find yourself writing sizeof(MyObjectiveCClass) you are almost certainly doing something horribly wrong that will be completely broken.