# Where are the synthesized ivars stored?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, xcode4

I've been reading up on the automatically synthesized ivars. My question is, "WHere are automatically they allocated?" I would have expected them to be part of self, so that I could see them in the debugger, but it seems that the only way I can see them is by invoking the accessor method (via the gdb 'po' command). Isn't there space in the class/object's struct (as there would be for an explicitly declared ivar)?

(Is there a description of the in-memory representation for a modern Objective-C object?)

Being a C guy, it makes me very uncomfortable to not to be able to see where everything is. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will tell you:
[How do automatic @synthesized ivars affect the *real* sizeof(MyClass)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076836/how-do-automatic-synthesized-ivars-affect-the-real-sizeofmyclass)

I am a C guy at heart too. Why bother using these auto generated ones? I like looking at a class and seeing what it holds onto in terms of data.

Interesting: Neat how they took the 64 bit change to make things better.
http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html

Comment: Is the limitation still true that you can't use dynamic ivars on the simulator? If so that sort of cans them on the iPhone. Plus developing for OS X means 32 bit binaries, so I can't see them there, either, in real life.

Comment: I believe you can use them in the Simulator now, but I don't remember for certain.

Comment: The simulator's runtime and the device runtime work the same.

Comment: I'd read a lot of the entries related to this, so I think I know how it works. The automatically synthesized ivars do not appear in the debugger under 'self', however. The only way to see them is to use the gdb command line. The values have to be stored somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: In watching one of the Apple dev conference videos, it turns out that there is a bug in some version of Xcode that caused it to not show the inferred ivars.

Answer (score 1):

They are added to the objective-c object (which is a C structure) no different to a regular ivar, so for example:

```
@interface TestObject : NSObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int theInt;

@end

@implementation QuartzTestView

@synthesize theInt;

@end
```

You can refer to `theInt` ivar directly (not through property accessors) either:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    theInt = 5;
}
```

**OR**

```
- (void)someOtherMethod {
    self->theInt = 10;
}
```

Comment: You say, "no different than a regular ivar", but regular ivars show up in the debugger, those without an explicit declaration do not show up.

Comment: @wrlee, indeed they do, and in the order you synthesize them.  See [this](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/xmeQ0hYCt7SAL1DNFXRhfzhx437tMWI6RAv8g-2VuS0?feat=directlink) screen shot, and note that `self` is expanded in the watch window.

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html - using the modern runtime an instance variable "will be synthesized for you". It can be nice to add a variable yourself instead though (so that you can see it when debugging in self), however you have to be careful not to do direct assignments to the instance variable for retain or copy based properties.

Comment: That was the basis for my confusion: that I couldn't see the ivars in the debugger. I think of the @property/@synthesize directives as convenience tags and that the resulting code should have been exactly as if I'd specified the ivars explicitly; since they do not show up in the debugger, that does not appear to be the case. So, what is really going on, that the debugger does not show the ivars as part of 'self"?

Comment: In watching one of the Apple dev conference videos, it turns out that there is a bug in some version of Xcode that caused it to not show the inferred ivars.