# Difference between declaring an attribute and a @property in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I know that the @property generates the getters and setters in Objective-c. But I've seen some classes where they declare attributes with their respective @property and some times just the @property with no attributes and seams to work the same way. Whats the difference?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076836/how-do-automatic-synthesized-ivars-affect-the-real-sizeofmyclass) should help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that the @property generates the getters and setters in Objective-c.

No you don't.  `@property` **declares** a property which is a getter and optionally a setter (for read/write properties).  The generation of the getter and setter is done by the `@synthesize` in the implementation (or by you writing the getter and setter).

> But I've seen some classes where they declare attributes with their respective @property

Do you mean like this?

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    Bar* anAttribute; // <<=== this is an instance variable
}

@property (retain) Bar* anAttribute;

@end
```

In the modern Objective-C run time, if you `@synthesize` the property, you can leave out the instance variable declaration and the compiler will put it in for you.  Whether you explicitly declare the instance variable or not is a matter of personal preference.

---

Just to confuse you a bit, in the very latest compiler, you can omit the `@synthesize` and the compiler will put it in for you as long as you haven't explicitly created a getter or setter.

Comment: Really? Which compiler allows you to omit synthesize statements?

Comment: @Moshe: It's in Xcode 4.4 apparently.  http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Apr/msg00037.html

Comment: great fun explanation

Answer (score 5):

Under ios 5.0, there are ten different attributes you can attach to a property declaration: nonatomic, readwrite, readonly, getter=*name*, setter=*name*, strong, retain, copy, weak, assign.  (strong, weak are new under ios 5.0 and are only meaningful if you use ARC).

nonatomic declares that variable access should *not* be protected against multithreaded concurrent access.  This isn't the default, although 99% of the time it's what you want (since this protection makes your code run slower with no benefit if you're not doing multithreading).

readwrite/readonly should be fairly obvious - readwrite is the default, and if you declare a property readonly, it has no setter.

getter=, setter= control what the getter & setter methods should be called.  If you omit them, they'll be called *property name* and set*property name*, respectively.

The remaining attributes (strong, weak, retain, copy, assign) are hints to the memory manager, and their behavior varies depending on whether you're using ARC or not.  If you're not, then the "retain" property tells the setter method to automatically call *retain* on any object that it gets a reference to.  This means that you must also call *release* in the deallocator.

The "assign" property tells the setter not to call *retain* - so if the object is released by another object, this pointer could be left dangling.

The "copy" property tells the setter to call *retain* and also to make a copy of the property - this is useful when you get, say, an NSDictionary and you don't want the caller to pass an instance of NSMutableDictionary and change the contents out from underneath you.

If you're using ARC, you'll normally only set "strong" or "weak".  (strong is a synonym for retain, so they can be used interchangeably).  "strong" tells ARC to retain the variable for you - "weak" tells it not to.  "weak" is useful when you have a potential "retain cycle" where object A refers to object B and object A - if they both retain each other, you have a memory leak, so you'll want to make one of them a weak reference.

Comment: Copy retains? Isn't the call to `copy` enough to increment the retain count?